# Executing functions in sequence defined in a package

Tags: oracle, plsql

I've been given the task of converting a stored procedure, with several CRUD operations, to a package with functions defined.

When I created the package in Oracle SQL Developer, I defined may functions:

```
FUNCTION func1 RETURN NUMBER;
FUNCTION func2 RETURN NUMBER;
etc...
```

I have corresponding code in the 'package body':

```
 FUNCTION func1 RETURN NUMBER
    IS
          BEGIN     
              -- some CRUD operation
          END;

          RETURN 0;
          COMMIT;

        EXCEPTION
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
           dbms_output.put_line('FUNCTION func1: error ' || ERR_NUM || ', Msg:' || ERR_MSG);
           ROLLBACK;
 END func1;
```

When I run them, I can choose which function to run from the list supplied.  My question is what do I need to write or do to have all functions run in sequence with one command?

thanks

Comment: It sounds like you could probably just add another method (function or procedure, as needed) in your package which calls them in order. There is nothing I know of which would do it for you.

Comment: BTW, your commit has no effect, as it comes after the return statement

Comment: If you want a more generic way to do this, you'd need to write a procedure that accepted an array of some object type, where the type had some kind of 'run()' method so that the procedure could step through the array executing each one's method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to run some procedures in a given order, you need to build a procedure or an anonymous block that calls the procedures in the right order.
For example:

```
create or replace package aPackage is
    procedure runAll;
end;   

create or replace package body aPackage is
    procedure proc1 is
    begin
        dbms_output.put_line('Procedure 1');
    end proc1;
    --
    procedure proc2 is
    begin
        dbms_output.put_line('Procedure 2');
    end proc2;

    procedure runAll is    
    begin
        proc1;
        --
        proc2;
        --
    end runAll;

end;
```

The call:

```
SQL> exec aPackage.runAll;
Procedure 1
Procedure 2

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

I used procedures just to call them without need to assign the result to a variable, but the idea is the same for functions.

With functions:

```
create or replace package aPackageFun is
    function runAll return number;
end;    

create or replace package body aPackageFun is
    function fun1 return number  is
    begin
        dbms_output.put_line('Inside function 1');
        return 1;
    end fun1;
    --
    function fun2 return number  is
    begin
        dbms_output.put_line('Inside function  2');
        return 2;
    end fun2;

    function runAll return number is  
        vNum1 number;
        vNum2 number;  
    begin
        vNum1 := fun1();
        --
        vNum2 := fun2();
        --
        return vNum1 + vNum2; 
    end runAll;

end;
```

The call:

```
SQL> select aPackageFun.runAll() from dual;

APACKAGEFUN.RUNALL()
--------------------
                   3

Inside function 1
Inside function  2
SQL>
```

About your code, notice that you have a `commit` after a `return`: the `commit` will never be executed.

Comment: In case it's not obvious to others, the stored procedure that calls the other stored procedures must come after the stored procedure that it's calling.